# How to Externalise files to PCF

Tags: cloud-foundry

How to provide any external files to PCF(Pivotal cloud foundary)  which are needed in my application.

(For eg: any external xml,html,xsl,etc files)

Comment: Can you please clarify your use case? Are you looking to externalized configuration or other files? Why are the xml / html files external?

Comment: @ K.AJ some of our configurations are stored in global repository for all applications so can i use something like confug server

Comment: Config server is meant for externalizing properties. That said the way a config server looks up the config file is based on the app name. So, if you have a shared config file across applications,  you have to follow the naming conventions.
BTW, for a config server you can use git or vault, but cannot use svn etc

Comment: @K.AJ Thanks a lot